# node js code flow for dynamic drop down values

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nodes

If i want to filter data on page on the basis of drop down values where all drop down values
are coming from database . how will be the flow of code to achieve this?

Comment: Some code ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: code is calling displadata.js file on particular route and fetching data from database in this file and sending to view like router.get('/customer',DisplayAllRecords);